# Multidimensional vector classification opencv

Tags: c++, opencv, vector

I'll start with what I want to do. I have a vector full of points.

```
   vector<Vec2f> points;
```

I'd like to group them according to the distance they are from the starting point and if the point is further away create a new entry and do the same.

For example 1st point is at 50, 50 and there are a few points in the distance of 0,0 - 100,100 then there are more points in various distances.

This is the data element I want at the end:

```
vector<vector<Vec2f>> groupedpoints;
```

To populate groupedpoints I would make a for cycle comparing each Vec2f points data element to the 1st Vec2f data element. If the conditions are not met and the point is too far away I would push_back groupedpoints and start populating it.

```
groupedpoints[clusternumber][clusterpointnumber]
```

So the 1st point would place at groupedpoints[0][0]
Other points that meet the criteria would place at groupedpoints[0][1....]
If a point that does not meet the criteria is found I would create a new entry in groupedpoints[1][0] and then place subsequent points in groupedpoints[1][1....] so on and so on until all the points are classified.

The problem is I have no idea how to initialize a new entry in groupedpoints the .push_back method would store all the values.

Is there any way to overcome this? I have something like a workaround in this:

```
groupedpoints.resize(1);
groupedpoints[0].push_back(points[0]);
```

But I don't want to resize my vector each time I need a value at the end. Without the resize I get an error on the very 1st write - Vector subscript out of range. If I resize it everything works fine.

Comment: Please specify the meanings of slines and lines. I thought you want to put elements from `points` in `groupedpoints` so what do you want to push back in `slines`?

Comment: Sorry. At some point I went back into my own coding world and used the variables there :D 
slines = groupedpoins 
points = lines
(edited original post)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is because in the beginning you don't initialize `groupedpoints`. When you call `resize` then the vector's size will be set to 1 so it contains exactly 1 element. What you have to do is to *initialize* the variable `groupedpoints` (this you can also do by calling `resize` but you only have to call it once).

```
vector<vector<Vec2f> > groupedpoints = vector<vector<Vec2f> >(1,vector<Vec2f>(0,Vec2f());
//here you use the contructors of vector and Vec2f respectively to make groupedpoints contain exactly one (empty) element which is the first group;

vector<vector<Vec2f> > groupedpoints;
groupedpoints.resize(1);
//this will have the same effect since the inner vector is initialized using its default constructor (= empty);
```

Comment: If I only had to use it 1ce it wouldn't be a problem. However in my case I have to use resize before every .push_back operation or else I receive this error: http://i.imgur.com/YDb8mGV.png

To get around it I use this:

     vecs++;
     groupedpoints.resize(vecs);
     groupedpoints[vecs-1].push_back(points[i]);

Vecs being a counter for space needed.

Comment: Then please provide us with exactly what you are doing (i.e. your whole code on some external site) because the above approach should really work. Note that when you create a new group (this is when you do `vecs++` and `groupedpoints.resize(vecs)` atm) you first have to push back an element in `groupedpoints` like `groupedpoints.push_back(vector<Vec2f>(0))` which extends `groupedpoints` by an empty group. Then you can do `(groupedpoints.end()-1)->push_back(points[i])` which inserts `point[i]` in the last group.

Comment: Thank you. That comment explained everything perfectly and worked. I'll use the 

groupedpoints.push_back(vector<Vec2f>(0)); (groupedpoints.end()-1)->push_back(points[i]) approach.